# Cakephp $useTable does not work

Tags: cakephp, models, cakephp-model, cakephp-2.2

I'm developing a web app on CakePHP 2.2.3 with an already database(MySQL) existing. This database is in spanish language so my app is in spanish and I get the error "Error: Table ordens for model orden was not found in datasource default."

My Model:

Orden.php

```
class Orden extends AppModel{
    public $name = 'Orden';
    public $useTable = 'ordenes';
    public $primaryKey = 'idorden';

}
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ordenes` (
  `idOrden` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- more columns --
  PRIMARY KEY (`idOrden`)
)
```

APP/config/database.php

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'USER',
    'password' => 'PASS',
    'database' => 'DATABASE',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

}

According to docs I can declare $useTable with the corresponding table  but this does not work. Can anyone help me, please?

EDIT: Same problem with `$primaryKey` but variable `$name` has the right value.

Comment: Set your debug=2 and check the SQL log at bottom of page for clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a half and ugly solution.
Check the following code:

```
class OrdenesController extends AppController{

    public $name = 'Orden'; 
    public $uses = array('orden'); 
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function index(){
        $this->orden->useTable = 'ordenes';
        $this->set('ord', $this->orden->find('all'));      
    }
}
```

If I set the variable `$useTable` in `OrdenesController`, I can get the array of Ordenes. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: On the controller, you're using a different model ("orden", with lowercase "o"). That model is created onthe fly. That's why.

Answer (score 1):

You found the answer to your question, with a partial solution that is valid for you, but in fact it is a workaround that will not be working in any case.

I wanted to answer to the question:

"If I set the variable `$useTable` in OrdenesController, I can get the array of Ordenes. Can anyone tell me why?"

That you asked in you own solution <del>(cannot comment yet)</del>.

First one important note CakePHP throws the error:

`Error: Table <table name> for model <model name> was not found in datasource default.`

1. If table `<table name>` for model `<model name>` was not found in
   datasource default.(obvously)
2. But also in some cases if cakePHP cannot find the model `<modelname>`, which can be quite confusing.

The reason why what you did worked in your model is because when in your controller you write:

```
public $uses = array('orden');
```

CakePHP assumes $this->order as a Model and tries to find the model **order** in the folder Model (note that the file CakePHP will be looking for is **order.php** NOT **Order.php** it also will be expecting the class to be called **order** and NOT **Order**, even though you can change the Model's class name setting `$name`).

If it finds the model it tries to retrieve the data from the default settings for the model, or the settings set (as in your case the `$useTable` and `$primaryKey`).
If it cannot find the table then the error message is displayed indicating correctly the fact that it cannot find the table.

But if it does not find the model cakePHP tries then to instantiate the model, in this case with the default values, since no setting has been made (model is instantiated *"on fly"*). This means it uses *default* as datasource and being the the english plural of *orden*, *ordens* cakePHP tries to find *ordens* table (this is the standard way for cakePHP to name tables for models and orden is not an English word).
Since this table is not in *default* datasource it throws the error, but the real error is the non-existing file.

When you change the `$useTable` value in your model you thought that it will be use instead of the standard but cakePHP is NOT using your model *Orden* but the *"on fly"* instantiated model *orden* since it cannot find the model *orden* as the error message sais (your class is call *Orden* not *orden*).

As such, any default operation soported by any default model (for example *find* and the like) will work.
Then you call `$this->orden->find('all')` it will perfectly work but if you create any function in your model (the one you think you are using *Orden*) and call it, you will get an error since they don't exist in the *"on fly"* version.

For this reason your workaround will work but only very partially.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your table exists in your default datasource? CakePHP can use multiple datasources to handle multiple connections (see `APP/config/database.php`)

Incorrect, but nothing to do with your problem, is `public $primaryKey = 'idorden';`. Looking at your MySQL code, it should say: `public $primaryKey = 'idOrden';`

Do you have debug mode on? Try flushing your cache in `/APP/tmp/cache`.

Maybe your using table prefixes and the table in your database is not prefixed?

Did you copied and pasted the error message? It is unlikely that models are written in small caps.

You can also define custom singular and plural forms of your words making using `$useTable` irrelevant. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#inflection-configuration

But please either look at your database configuration or show us the code to let us see if you are using multiple datasources. Otherwise check with the help of the mysql prompt or tools like phpMyAdmin if the table really exists.

Comment: I added  my database.php in the first post also I have been deleted files in `/APP/tmp/cache` as you said but the error keep.
message "Error: Table ordens for model orden was not found in datasource default." was copied and pasted here.
I also read about singular and plural forms but I don't understand.
Finally, I am sure that the table exists.

Comment: You are using two different models, as already said. Correct `public $uses = array('orden');` to `public $uses = array('Orden');` (notice the capital O) and leave out `$this->orden->useTable = 'ordenes';` (both in your controller)

Answer (score -1):

I met this problem too. The reason is my model php file name `ScheduleAd.php`, but I wrote `"ScheduleAD"` for uses array.

```
public $uses = array('ScheduleAD');
```

So, please check if your model file name and model class name and the name in $uses array , they must totally equal:)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @jeremy I am of a different opinion. I think user posted this answer because this is what solved his problem, he arrived at with the same symptoms. It is useful to have this post for himself for future reference.

Comment: Sounds like a "me too" answer to a  2 year old question.  If its not, it should be edited to explain how this fixes the problem.